# editing treeview item do not automatically updates database

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtreeview, qstandarditemmodel

I have a qtableview and Treeview in my program.
qtableview code is:

```
    void MainWindow::tableShow(QString mystrings)
{
    testModel = new QSqlTableModel(this);
    testModel->setTable("parts");
    if (mystrings=="")
    {
        testModel->setFilter("");
    }
    else
    {
    testModel->setFilter("type='"+mystrings+"'");
    }
    testModel->select();
    ui->tableView->setModel(testModel);
    }
```

it works just fine and the very interesting ability it has is you can edit cells and database updates automatically.
Now I have made a TreeView with this code:

```
    void MainWindow::treeView2()
{
    QStandardItemModel *myModel= new QStandardItemModel;
    QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem();
    item = myModel->invisibleRootItem();
    myQuery.exec("select groupName from maingroup");
    while(myQuery.next()){

        QString temp =(myQuery.value(0).toString());
        QStandardItem *parItem= new QStandardItem(temp);
        item->appendRow(parItem);
        QSqlQuery childqry;
        childqry.exec("select sub from subgroup where main = '"+temp+"'");
                while(childqry.next()){
            QStandardItem *childItem= new QStandardItem(childqry.value(0).toString());
            parItem->appendRow(childItem);
        }
    }
    ui->treeView->setModel(myModel);
    ui->treeView->expandAll();
}
```

but editting item in this treeview do not updates the database and after restarting the program the item is like before. what should i do to automatically update database with new value that edited in treeview?
thanks in advance.

Comment: QStandardItemModel only reads the QSqlQuery result and then forgets it, so it only updates the data that I load but not the data in the database. In conclusion, QStandardItemModel only copies data from the database and when you edit the QTreeView you only edit the copy but not the database.

Comment: Can you share your .db if you are using sqlite or a .sql if you are using another database? to be able to test the problem and provide a possible solution

Comment: You should create your own model or use an already implemented (e.g : [sqltreemodel](http://inspireforyou.info/reports/src/models/sqltreemodel.cpp) )

Comment: @TungLeThanh. thanks
as I am a newbie in this field could you give me an example for creating own model or using sqltreemodel?

Comment: You can see the explanation of the author [here](https://www.mimec.org/blog/qsqlquerymodel-and-qtreeview-part-1)

Comment: @TungLeThanh I read the reference you said but I think it is not for someone like me. I need something like a step by step learning of it or at least a simple example to know what happend. thanks by the way

Comment: @eyllanesc
yes of course. this is the link: https://files.fm/u/chpr9nzv
 thanks in advance